# onchange only works for the first row in a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Am selecting an item from a select-option tag in a table to populate records from a database to fill another select-option tag, but unfortunately, it only works for the first table row. When I add another table row with jquery, it does not work in the new added table row.

**The HTML table**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" type="checkbox"/></th>
        <th width="10%">Credit Type</th>
        <th width="20%">Credit Account</th>
        <th width="15%">Fund</th>
        <th width="15%">Amount</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
           <td>
             <select name="fund_id" class="form control" id="type_1">
             <option></option>
             <option value="23">Expense</option>
             <option value="3">Fixed Asset</option>
             <option value="8">Current Asset</option>
             <option value="5">Current Liability</option>
            <option value="4">Non-Current Liability</option>                                    
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="credit_1" name="cr_ac" class="form-control" >
             <option></option>
            </select>
         </td>
         <td> <input type="text" name="fund[]" id="fund_1" ></td>
         <td><input type="text"  name="amount[]" id="amount_1"></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

**The script that add new row to table**

```
<script>
    var i=$('table tr').length;
    $(".addmore").on('click',function(){
        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
        html += '<td><select name="fund_id" class="form-control" id="type_'+i+'"><option></option><option value="23">Expense</option><option value="3">Fixed Asset</option><option value="8">Current Asset</option><option value="5">Current Liability</option><option value="4">Non-Current Liability</option></select></td>';
        html += '<td><select id="credit_'+i+'" name="cr_ac" class="form-control" ><option></option></select></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="fund[]" id="fund_'+i+'"></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="amount[]" id="amount_'+i+'"></td>';
       html += '</tr>';
        $('table').append(html);
        i++;
    });
</script>
```

**The onchange function with ajax**

```
<script>
for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

    (function(i) {

       $(document).ready(function(){

          $("#type_"+i).change(function(){

            var id=$("#type_"+i).val();
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;

            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "populate_debit_type.php",
                   data: dataString,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function(html){

                          $("#credit_"+i).html(html);
                   } 
            });

          });

       });

    })(i);

}
</script>
```

**The PHP script that fetch the db records**

```
<?php

include "includes/kon/db_connect.php";

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    // query for options based on value
    $sql = $link->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE parent_id = '$id' OR ext_parent = '$id'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

       echo '<option value="'.$row['account_code'].'">'.$row['account_name'].'</option>';

   }
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you registered the `change` event before you dynamically create & inject the new rows. So the code you registered for the change event is only applicable to the items present in the page during your event registration. It won't work for future(dynamically injected to DOM) elements.

For current and future elements to work, you should use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegation.

When you add a new row, give a css class name to your select element.

```
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    //existing code
    html+= '<td><select class="form-control mySelect" id="type_'+i+'">'
});
```

and use this new css class as your jQuery selector to register the `change` event code using jQuery on method. Also in the success event on your ajax call to get the data for the second dropdown, you should use the `closest()` method to get a reference of the parent tr and use `find()` method to get a reference to the second dropdown.

```
$(function(){

   $(document).on("change",".mySelect",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var _this=$(this);
      // use _this, which is jQuery object of the dropdown user changed
      var id =_this.val();

     //Get the second dropdown
     var _crac=_this.closest("tr").find("select[name='cr_ac']");

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "populate_debit_type.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
               _crac.html(html);
           } 
      });

   });

});
```

Comment: Do I have to use the ( for loop ) again? can you please help me out with the ajax. Thanks

Comment: Please the onchange works perfectly now but the problem is the success function in the ajax. It only populate the first row

Comment: You should use `closest()` and `find()`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

for (var i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

```
(function(i) {
```

$(document.body).on('change', '#type_"+i`enter code here`', function (event) {

```
        var id=$("#type_"+i).val();
        var dataString = 'id='+ id;

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "populate_debit_type.php",
               data: dataString,
               cache: false,
               success: function(html){

                      $("#credit_"+i).html(html);
               } 
        });

      });

   });
```

(i);

}